# Zend HashTable SIGSEGV

Tags: c, zend-framework

I've been experimenting with PHP SAPI and the Zend Engine to try and embed PHP within an application I'm writing. I've hit a bit of a snag. I was having problems setting global variables within the PHP init function. I have gone right back to basics and taken an example off of Zend's API.

```
#include <php_embed.h>
#include <zend_API.h>
#include <zend.h>
#include <zend_alloc.h>
#include <zend_compile.h>
#include <zend_hash.h>
#include <zend_execute.h>
#include <zend_globals_macros.h>
#include <zend_ptr_stack.h>
#include <zend_constants.h>
#include <zend_extensions.h>

static int php_ub_write(const char *str, unsigned int str_length TSRMLS_DC);

static char *poutput = NULL;
static int poutput_mal;

static int register_globals(void)
{
    zend_first_try {

        HashTable *ht = NULL;

        // allocate memory
        //ht = emalloc(sizeof(HashTable));
        ALLOC_HASHTABLE(ht);

        // initialize it internal state

        zend_hash_init(ht, 50, NULL, ZVAL_PTR_DTOR, 0);

        // destroy the hash table

        zend_hash_destroy(ht);

        // free the hash table itself

        FREE_HASHTABLE(ht);
    } zend_end_try();
}

static void startup_php(void)
{
    /* Create "dummy" argc/argv to hide the arguments
     * meant for our actual application */

    int argc = 1;
    char *argv[2] = { "cHTTPD", NULL };
    register_globals();
    php_embed_module.ub_write = php_ub_write;
    php_embed_init(argc, argv);// PTSRMLS_CC);
}

static void shutdown_php(void)
{
    php_embed_shutdown(TSRMLS_C);
}

static void execute_php(char *filename)
{
    zend_first_try {
        zend_file_handle script;

        script.type = ZEND_HANDLE_FP;
        script.filename = filename;
        script.opened_path = NULL;
        script.free_filename = 0;

        if (!(script.handle.fp = fopen(script.filename, "rb")))
            return;// NULL;

        php_execute_script(&script TSRMLS_CC);
    } zend_end_try();
}

int php(char *filename, char **string) {
    startup_php();

    execute_php(filename);

    *string = malloc(strlen(poutput) + 1);
    strcpy(*string, poutput);
    free(poutput);

    shutdown_php();

    return 0;
}

static int php_ub_write(const char *str, unsigned int str_length TSRMLS_DC)
{
    char *tmp;

    if (poutput == NULL)
    {
        poutput = malloc(8000);//str_length + 1);
        poutput_mal = 8000;
        strncpy(poutput, str, str_length);
    }
    else
    {
        if ((strlen(poutput) + str_length) >= poutput_mal)
        {
            tmp = malloc(strlen(poutput));
            strncpy(tmp, poutput, strlen(poutput));

            poutput = malloc(strlen(poutput) + str_length + 1);
            poutput_mal = strlen(poutput) + str_length + 1;

            strncpy(poutput, tmp, strlen(tmp));

            free(tmp);
        }
        strncat(poutput, str, str_length);

    }

    return str_length;
}


int main()
{
    char *string;
    php("/home/durir/web/index.php", &string);
}
```

index.php code:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

This still SIGSEGVs on the second line of code (ALLOC_HASHTABLE) tracing it back to emalloc. Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: There's not much we can tell you without the details of the `ALLOC_HASHTABLE` macro / function.  You've gone a long way in the direction of a [mcve], but you're not there yet.

Comment: Wild guess: `ALLOC_HASHTABLE()` has conditional code intended to allow it to serve both to allocate and to *re*allocate; to distinguish which is wanted, it tests whether the argument is `NULL`.  If that's the case, then you want to initialize `ht` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the `PHP` source, you'll find that the `ALLOC_HASHTABLE()` macro expands to run a bunch of code from `zend_alloc.c`. What it is doing is using its own memory manager and you're calling it before the zend memory manager has been initialized. To fix this, simply insert `start_memory_manager();` before `ALLOC_HASHTABLE(ht);`:

```
static int register_globals() {
    zend_first_try {
        start_memory_manager();
        HashTable *ht;
        ALLOC_HASHTABLE(ht);
        zend_hash_init(ht, 50, NULL, ZVAL_PTR_DTOR, 0);
        zend_hash_destroy(ht);
        FREE_HASHTABLE(ht);
        return SUCCESS;
    } zend_end_try();
    return FAILURE;
}
```

After doing this, your code works as expected (tested on macOS 10.12.1 Sierra).

**Edit:**

Actually, for better encapsulation, you should probably put `start_memory_manager();` before `register_globals();` in `startup_php()` and not in `register_globals()`.